# How do implement the effect of blur on transparent materials?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, shaders, transparency, blur

I'm trying to create a blur effect when a clear light passes through a transparent material. Here's a quick summary of the picture:

[image]

And when an object is close to a transparent material, it should be more visible than it is away from a transparent material.

Here's a quick summary of the picture:

[image]

I've seen this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEXjHG_qDzk) for implement this, but I'm not trying to implement glass, because I'm trying to implement a [protective film](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHSwC.jpg), so it doesn't fit my procedures.

[image]

Comment: that looks like a description of glass to me...

Comment: @Luciano Can only glass material achieve this effect? What's different from glass, it doesn't have reflections.

Comment: Glass BSDF has reflection and refraction of course. That tutorial is good for your protective film. You need to try it first.

Comment: @Hikariztw But, I didn't see the "Screen Space Reflections" Panel. And, blender version of the tutorial is same my blender version. But, I think is little different.

Comment: No offense, but type `Screen Space Reflections Blender` in Google. And the first Blender Manual tell you the panel is in *Render Panel*. For the version different, tutorial use an early version of beta. But it should be almost the same

Comment: @Hikariztw I'm trying to create a effect on a cycle engine. But, the 'Screen Space Reflections' function is only available on the Eevee engine.

Comment: Cycles doesn't need that. EEVEE use **Screen Space Reflections** to imitating Cycles reflection light path. You shouldn't worry that much in Cycles. But Cycles doesn't have a **Studio Preview**. So you will need to setup your own light to see how reflection works in Cycles.

Comment: Thank you @Hikariztw! you're so best.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple solution is to create a render pass for the glass and use it as a mask to add blur in the compositor. Of course, to implement the depth effect, you would also then need to render out a depth mask to use as the blur amount, and then your passes are adding up. That's a lot of rendering and compositing just to avoid a glass material, but this method can sometimes end up rendering faster because it avoids some of the typical issues associated with rendering glass.

Answer (score 2):

Increase the roughness on a glass shader.

No roughness:

[image]

Some roughness:

[image]

Even more roughness:

[image]

Blur will work just fine with distance, the closer the object is to the window, it will be sharper.

[image]

[image]